# HTML + CSS Table with different size columns?

Tags: html, css

This is what I'm looking to get:

[image: layout I am trying to achieve]
I'd like a category bar on the side, and all the main content in the right box. Right now, I'm attempting to do this with tables, and it's proving to be difficult.
Are there any useful CSS functions that I should be using?

Edit: Sorry, here's the current code:

```
<body>
<img src="xxx">

<table width="100%" border=1>
    <col width="30%">
    <col width="70%">

    <tr>
        <th id="row1">
            Categories
        </th>
        <th id="row1">
            Main Content
        </th>
    </tr>

    </div>


    <tr>
        <th>
            Category Header
        </th>
        <td id="main-content">
            45645
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <li>
            Category Entry
            </li>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

And my current stylesheet:

```
li {
list-style-type: none;
}

#row1 {
color: ;
}

#main-content {
padding: 9999999;
margin-bottom: 9999999;
}
```

Comment: It is better to use DIV .. than table for layout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  background: red;
  padding: 2%;
}

aside {
  clear: left;
  float: left;
  width: 28%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  padding: 2%;
  background: blue;
}

main {
  float: left;
  width: 68%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  padding: 2%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>This is the header. This is the header. This is the header. This is the header. This is the header. This is the header. This is the header. This is the header. </header>
  <aside>This is the sidebar. This is the sidebar. This is the sidebar. This is the sidebar. This is the sidebar. This is the sidebar. This is the sidebar. This is the sidebar. This is the sidebar. This is the sidebar. This is the sidebar. This is the sidebar.
    This is the sidebar. This is the sidebar. This is the sidebar. This is the sidebar. This is the sidebar. This is the sidebar. This is the sidebar. This is the sidebar. This is the sidebar. </aside>
  <main>This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main
    content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This
    is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content.
    This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main
    content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This
    is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. This is the main content. </main>
</body>
```

This is a responsive design, but if you don't want it to be, just apply fixed widths.

Comment: This is cool. I'm trying to set it up for my ebay store, so the responsive design is perfect. I'm not entirely sure how ebay will take special syntax like <aside>, but I'll try it out. Also, ebay won't let me use stylesheets that select all of something, so could I use <aside id="aside1"> ?

Comment: `<aside>` isn't "special syntax", it is a tag in HTML5 as are `<header>` and `<main>` — browsers that don't know these tags should treat them like a `<div>`

Comment: As Stephen P said, the tags aren't "special syntax". And yes you can use `<aside id="aside1">` or <aside class="aside1">

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for the help fellas. This is great and I didn't know this functionality existed outside of bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTML5 semantic as header, aside or main and CSS Flexbox.
Try this snippet :

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
header {
  flex: 0 1 100%;
  background: red;
}
aside {
  flex: 1 0 25%;
  background: green;
}
main {
  flex: 1 0 75%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>Header content</header>
  <aside>Aside content</aside>
  <main>Main content</main>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet it to use `colspan=2` for the first row `td's` and put a div inside first `td` of the second row with `height="80%"`:

```html
<table style="height: 200px; width: 200px;">
  <colgroup>
    <col width="30%">
    <col width="70%">
   </colgroup>
      <tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black; height: 20px;" colspan="2">First row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="border: none; padding: 0; margin: 0; vertical-align: top;">
            <div style="height: 80%; border: 1px solid black; margin-top: 0; padding-top: 20px;"> Test <div>
        </td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black">$100</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! However, how would I make the text in the second column wrap? I'd like to write paragraphs in there, and even add some images.

Comment: you can use `word-wrap: break-word;` or `white-space:pre-wrap`

Comment: @Chase - since you are learning, learn how to use proper tags and CSS to style them -- do **not** use a table to lay-out how you want your page to look. so 1995.

Comment: Agree with @StephenP you can do the same with a bunch of div's

Comment: Yeah totally agree. Tables are not the way to go. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you using divs with css, Doesn't seem right to use table in such case.

If you're new to all the html and css things try out [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com)

Super easy and pre-made css. You can see examples and follow simple tutorials.